# Trying to decode string without knowing its encoding scheme

Tags: python, web-scraping, cookies, encoding, request

I'm using Selenium to scrape a website. However, to speed up the process I'm trying to move my scraper to requests.

My search is based on ids. For instance, I'm trying to scrape the following ids :

```
id1 = "1144135234"
id2 = "2267914663"
```

Looking at the request I see that the following strings are sent as "ids" :

```
id1_request = 'ADRUM_BTa': 'R:182|g:400c052d-7899-4231-b833-9bdee9a8b91c|n:customer1_1bed2d85-d0ef-4ba4-a5d6-23509081913e'
id2_request = 'ADRUM_BTa': 'R:182|g:c610320d-16ee-480d-8228-337525d7ca8b|n:customer1_1bed2d85-d0ef-4ba4-a5d6-23509081913e'
```

For instance, this is what is sent for id2 :

```
cookies = {
    '_ga_H4QZ8VCDEC': 'GS1.1.1661535243.2.1.1661535764.0.0.0',
    '_ga': 'GA1.1.1271540775.1661453126',
    '_pk_ref.11.201c': '%5B%22%22%2C%22%22%2C1673890679%2C%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F%22%5D',
    '_pk_id.11.201c': '59d75d6a16270d98.1663093017.',
    '_ga_1KE8QT0F05': 'GS1.1.1664988466.10.0.1664988466.0.0.0',
    '_ga_39REY8D2J0': 'GS1.1.1669053364.1.1.1669053375.0.0.0',
    '_ga_HHWRTT2VYV': 'GS1.1.1671129137.3.0.1671129137.0.0.0',
    '_ga_KXSJJLF41B': 'GS1.1.1673461437.1.1.1673461509.60.0.0',
    'WT.co_f': '25a97c9156e0c44e4e91673890678904',
    'WT_FPC': 'id=25a97c9156e0c44e4e91673890678904:lv=1673890682113:ss=1673890678904',
    '_pk_ses.11.201c': '1',
    'ASP.NET_SessionId': 'reuyhskz11v0r4sdpg1cv0zb',
    'LGSIEE': 'Cusr=EM2PROD&Iep=0',
    'LGSIEET1Utilisateur': 'Key=8fb51683-63c3-4a08-b54d-7bc9c13ecd92',
    'LGSIEET1JETON': 'IDUTL=8fb51683-63c3-4a08-b54d-7bc9c13ecd92&ID=c66124c7-6db1-4d79-b7f5-172c90438ed6',
    'K1LNG': 'F',
    'ADRUM_BTa': 'R:182|g:400c052d-7899-4231-b833-9bdee9a8b91c|n:customer1_1bed2d85-d0ef-4ba4-a5d6-23509081913e',
    'SameSite': 'None',
    'ADRUM_BT1': 'R:182|i:11162|e:135',
    'EtatCadri-GR03A2_19A_PIU_RechEnt_PC-reuyhskz11v0r4sdpg1cv0zb': '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',
}
```

Intuitively, I would say that in some way :

```
1144135234 = 400c052d-7899-4231-b833-9bdee9a8b91c
2267914663 = c610320d-16ee-480d-8228-337525d7ca8b
```

Is there a way to try and guess how id1 and id2 become respectively id1_request and id2_request ? Or is this `400c052d-7899-4231-b833-9bdee9a8b91c` an know encoded form ?

I tried to decode the request ids using some decoders but without success.

Comment: I can't speak for how they corollate but `400c052d-7899-4231-b833-9bdee9a8b91c` and `c610320d-16ee-480d-8228-337525d7ca8b` look like [`UUID`s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier).

Comment: i think it would be helpful if you put product pages related to ids and site urls ? is it possible that your assumption on the relationship between id and uuid is wrong ?

Comment: @Axe319 thx. I didn't know about UUIDs. Seems to be generated randomly unfortunately so I guess I'll need to stick with Selenium.

Comment: @DouxDoux which website you're scrapping and which data you need from there?